# Oclif - How to use compiled JS instead of TS

Tags: typescript, oclif

I have a CMD project based on oclif framework written on TypeScript. I'm wondering - is it possible to compile `.ts` into `.js` for production use?

I tried to compile files into `./lib` folder, then run a command `./bin/run hello` - Oclif still uses `.ts` version from the `./src` folder.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing - did you find a solution?